# MsiEnumRelatedProducts Invalid Parameter

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-installer

Attempting to use MsiEnumRelatedProducts with various input is constantly returning only ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETERS for me.  The documentation doesn't give any details on what the source of the invalid parameter could be but I've tried many different options.  Currently I have this code below to demonstrate the problem.  Replace the with a valid upgrade guid.

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const wchar_t* upgrade = L"812D9038-YOUR-GUID-B2EB-64F4E0B3FB3D";
    wchar_t product[39];
    DWORD index = 0;

```
switch (MsiEnumRelatedProducts(upgrade, 0, index++, product)) {
case ERROR_SUCCESS:
    wcout << L"ERROR_SUCCESS" << endl;
    break;
case ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
    wcout << L"ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS" << endl;
    break;
case ERROR_BAD_CONFIGURATION:
    wcout << L"ERROR_BAD_CONFIGURATION" << endl;
    break;
case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
    wcout << L"ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER" << endl;
    break;
case ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY:
    wcout << L"ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY" << endl;
    break;
default:
    wcout << L"DEFAULT" << endl;
    break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing your upgrade code in curly brackets so it looks like {GUID}.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Thank you.